# Cannot add or update a child row error mysql

Tags: mysql

I just got this error and I'm mot sure what it is about. Please let me know how I can fix it?

Thanks

> Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails
>   (`db_test`.`part`, CONSTRAINT `part_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`car_id`)
>   REFERENCES `car` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE)

Comment: where is your query ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your table has a foreign key constraint, which means any values of `part.car_id` should be exists in `car.id`. When you try to add a new row(record) or update `part.car_id` to some value not exists in `car.id`, this error will occur.